# Can't get update one prompt for same variable over multiple tables

Tags: oracle-sql-developer, teradata

I've tried using the following:

```
select * from TABLE1 where COLUMN= :VAR
union
select * from TABLE2 where COLUMN= :VAR;
```

I'm getting the following error message back:

```
[Teradata Database] [TeraJDBC 14.10.00.26] [Error 3654]
[SQLState HY000] Corresponding select-list expressions are incompatible.
```

If I just run:

```
select * from TABLE1 where COLUMN= :VAR;
```

then it works, but I need to be able to answer one prompt for the same variable that is used across multiple tables. I'm using Oracle SQL Developer Version 4.0.3.16

Answer (score 1):

[3654   Corresponding select-list expressions are incompatible.](http://www.info.teradata.com/htmlpubs/DB_TTU_14_10/index.html#page/General_Reference/B035_1096_112K/Database.27.0935.html)

> Explanation:
>
> If a query contains a UNION, MINUS, or INTERSECT operator, then **the
>   data types for all select-list expressions must be compatible with the
>   corresponding expression in the select-list for the first SELECT in
>   the query**. All numeric data types are considered compatible. Character
>   data types are not compatible with numeric data types. Byte data types
>   are only compatible with byte data types. Graphic data types are only
>   compatible with graphic data types.

The datatypes of the columns in `TABLE1` and `TABLE2` do not match.